# Setting a dynamic initial index for template variable using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a CMS to create a front-end form where customers (theatre directors) can define several showtimes. I have a button they click to "add another" input field as needed (sidenote: I don't know how to enable a 'remove last' button using Vue, but that's another topic for another day).

I've gotten that working. But now, once a director has created their showtimes and they come back to edit them, I need the starting index of the Vue counter to be the number of fields that already exist. So if they've defined 3 showtimes already (0,1,2), the first field dynamically placed with Vue should start with 3.

Alternatively, I wonder if it'd be easier to generate an array of the existing data in Vue when the page loads, but I don't know where I'd start with that method.

Here's my HTML and Vue JS:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    timeslots: [
      {
        count: 0
      }
    ],
    count: 0
  },

  methods: {
    addAnother: function(){
      this.timeslots.push({
        count: ++this.count
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ performances }}
    <input name="performances[{{ zero_index }}][showtime]" value="{{ showtime }}">
  {{ /performances }}

  <template v-for="slot in timeslots">
    <input name="performances[@{{ slot.count }}][showtime]" value="{{ now }}">
  </template>
  
  <div>
    <button @click.prevent="addAnother">Add another</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help to move forward is appreciated!

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time following. Are the existing `timeslots` being set in Vue properly? Also is the index in the name needed? I think you can get away with changing `++this.count` to `this.timeslots.length + 1`. Still though, hard time following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself in shorter time than expected using the 2nd method I speculated about in my OP, and using `$index` instead of an arbitrary integer like `count`. This method requires the JS to be put directly in my template though, not in a separate file. But that's fine by me.

```
<div id="oven">
  <template v-for="biscuit in oven">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="performances[@{{ $index }}][showtime]" value="@{{ biscuit.showtime }}">
    </div>
  </template>
  <span class="add small black btn" @click="addAnother"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add another</span>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#oven',

  data: {
    oven: [
      {{ performances }}
      {
        showtime: "{{ showtime }}"
      },
      {{ /performances }}
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    addAnother: function(){
      this.oven.push({
        showtime: '{{ now modify_date="+2 months" format="Y-m-d" }} 7:30 PM'
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```